# Including an HTML Template in a Meteor Package with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to mimic the Telescope application structure in my own demo Meteor application. The way they have things setup means that all code is located within sub-packages, including HTML templates and such.

I have my Meteor app setup so that I have the following:

- client

  - layout.html (Contains head tag, used as the "base" for the page)
- server

  - index.js (Contains the configuration for the Iron router, such as the default `layoutTemplate`)
- packages

  - myapp-ui

    - client

      - dashboard.html
    - myapp-ui.js
    - package.js

Inside of the `package.js` file in my package, I have the following code when trying to load the HTML template:

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'myapp-ui',
    version: '0.0.1',
    documentation: null
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');

    api.use([
        'iron:router'
    ]);

    api.addFiles([
        'client/dashboard.html'
    ]);

    api.addFiles('myapp-ui.js');
});
```

The `myapp-ui.js` file contains code to try and get the `dashboard.html` code into my application:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('Dashboard');
});
```

The `dashboard.html` template is simply:

```
<template name="dashboard">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</template>
```

The problem is, when visiting the `localhost:3000` page that *should* load the dashboard, I get an error:

```
Couldn't find a template named "Dashboard" or "dashboard". Are you sure you defined it?
```

I am slightly confused, because I obviously have a template HTML file loaded with a template tag named "dashboard", and this file is loaded inside my package with `api.addFiles`. Do I need to use some other package to enable loading of HTML inside of packages, or is my code just incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to either uppercase of lowercase syntax for your template name, at the moment you have both `<template name="dashboard">` and `this.render('Dashboard');`.

Did you actually add your package to the app using `meteor add myapp-ui` ?

Try to depend on the `templating` package on the client and load `client/dashboard.htm` only on the client :

```
api.use("templating", "client");
[...]
api.addFiles("client/dashboard.html", "client");
```

Comment: Regardless of whether the template name is upper/lower case, I still get the same issue. The package is definitely added because the code to add the route to the router is running.